# How to solve the error ":37: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'" in Xcode, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, rss

I tried the Xcode Project which gets RSS and view the articles from the websites.
https://github.com/icanzilb/Advanced-RSS-reader

But I can't get the articles from some websites.

And the error

" :37: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' "

and

" *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 100 out of bounds; string length 77'
 "

have caused.
How can I solve this errors?

Comment: You are trying to access index greater than string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have string "Technerd". Here each character has its index. Here 'T' would be at Index 0 , 'e' at 1 , 'c' at 2 and so on upto 'd' at '7'.

Suppose I want to get substring "Tech" from "Technerd".

Here length of String is 8.

```
NSString *string = @"Technerd";
NSString *mySubString = [string substringToIndex:3];
NSLog(@"SubString : %@", mySubString);  // SubString : Tech
```

Here if i try to access index beyond the length of string then it will crash app.

We can not access index 8 for given string.

```
NSString *string = @"Technerd";
NSString *mySubString = [string substringToIndex:8];
NSLog(@"SubString : %@", mySubString);  // Crash App
```

You can get Word's length as given below:

```
NSString *string = @"Technerd";
NSInteger length  = str.length;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.But I don't know how to get the word's length and fix it from the cord....

Comment: Edited my answer to get length of word.